# Как создать "бесконечную" таблицу?

Tags: php

**Цель:** если $r=10, строится таблица 10x10, если $r=100...

**Что придумал:**

```
$r=10;
echo '<TABLE>';   
$x=1; 
while ($x<=$r) {
echo '<TR>'; 
    while ($x<=$r) {
        echo '<TD>1</TD>'; 
        $x++;
    }
echo '</TR>'; 
$x++;
}
echo '</TABLE>';
```

Но строиться только первая строка. В чем ошибка?

Comment: Попадая в первый цикл $x=1, потом попадаем во второй цикл. Переменная $x возрастает до 10. Выходим из второго цикла в первый уже со значением $x=10. Заканчиваем первый цикл и уже имеем $x=11

Comment: да, уже осознал эту промашку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Блин ребят, ну что за говнокод?

```
while ($x<=$r) { // раз $x<=$r
echo '<TR>'; 
    while ($x<=$r) {  // два $x<=$r
        echo '<TD>1</TD>'; 
        $x++;
```

Т.е. он правильно строит одну строку, потому что потом возвращается к первому циклу и условие не выполняется, и цикл заканчивается. Поменяй переменные во втором цикле

```
$r=10;
$x=1; 
echo '<TABLE>';   
while ($x<=$r) {
echo '<TR>'; 
    while ($xx<=$r) {
        echo '<TD>1</TD>'; 
        $xx++;
    }
echo '</TR>'; 
$x++;
}
echo '</TABLE>';
```

Допустим так. И счастье обеспечено!

Answer (score 3):

Меньше циклов - меньше гибкости, но пустую таблицу можно создать.

```
$r = 10;

$tds = str_repeat('<td> поле </td>', $r);
$trs = str_repeat("<tr> $tds </tr>", $r);
$table = "<table> $trs </table>";

echo $table;
```

Comment: спасибо, так намного аккуратней

Comment: пользуйтесь)

Answer (score 3):

```
$r=10;
echo '<TABLE>';   
$x=1;
$y=1;

while ($x<=$r) {
echo '<TR>'; 
    while ($y<=$r) {
        echo '<TD>1</TD>'; 
        $y++;
    }
echo '</TR>'; 
$x++;
}
echo '</TABLE>';
```

Comment: работает, спасибо